# GA import lifetime value using measurement protocol

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics

I'm currently using google-apps-script to upload match data on my crm id and a revenue value that I have, I'm looking to upload the data as revenue rather than to a custom dimension that i've defined of value (this currently works)

The import template I have currently is :

```
ga:dimension3, ga:dimension4
```

Again this allows me to map the keyed value to a secondary value however I'm looking to add the value to `lifetime value`

I think this is possible because under `User Data` in the create data import section of GA it says `Import user data such as customer segment, lifetime value or contract renewal month.`

This is using the data measurement protocol so I'm hoping this is the right place to post, if not could you please show me a better place to post this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about data import, that's not possible via the measurement protocol. Data import is a feature of the [management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/data-import).

Mind you that in a standard GA account imported data is applied to incoming hits and does not change data that is already collected (a GA360 account has the "query time import" feature that let's you apply imports to historical data), so this might somewhat less useful than you imagine.

The description you quoted does not refer to the lifetime report in GA (the data import feature precede that report), they are simply suggesting you can import a custom dimension and set it to a lifetime value.

Of course if you have the clientid/userid for the respective user you can simply send a "fake" hit with a user scoped custom dimension (but this, too, will not go into the lifetime value report).

Comment: Thank you for replying to this, I must be using the management api then (in sheets this comes under 'google analytics api').. it's all done using a google sheet. I've already set up somenthing that matches a clientid with a crm id which is mapped to a custom dimension, I was just sure that you could add lifetime value data/revenue data to it because of the way the `user data` section is worded with 'lifetime value'

Comment: That's a reasonable assumption, but it was already worded that way before GA even had a lifetime value report.

Comment: Fantastic! I think I've found a solution now that involves sending a tr using the measurement protocol after the event has happened, I'm not sure if that will update the event or send a new one, if it sends a new one I think the best solution is to create a seperate goal for the event with revenue being sent vs the event, I'm hoping this will maintain all of it's attribution (sources/session path etc) do you know much about how this will be attributed?

Comment: If you send an event via the measurement protocol it will create a new event in GA. There isn't really a way to "update" hits in Google Analytics once they have been send to your tracking property (except for the mentioned query time import in the paid version).

Comment: Thanks for this! that's what I thought, I'm going to have a separate event that is a 'sale' which will have the actual value added to it, will that value maintain attribution? 

I am testing this while also asking it's just that the event take time to come through etc

Comment: When triggering a new event using the measurement protocol when specifying a client id I'm trying to use a client id that I captured in the past, does this have a maximum time frame if so is there any other way to associate the event with the correct user?